# Is it possible to build JetBrans MPS editor into my program?

Tags: dsl, mps

They have a tool to design DSLs: https://www.jetbrains.com/mps/

Is it possible to embed editor from there into my program? Or the only purpose is to use it during development only (to compile from DSL)?

Comment: What platform you use for your application?

Comment: Not decided yet. I was thiking is is Java and portable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In principal, since the MPS editor is a Java Swing application, it could be embedded, however, the current wiring makes it not a trivial process. It is definitely off the beaten path.

The preferred way to create single-purpose IDEs around your DSLs is to build a standalone IDE, which leverages the IntelliJ platform and bundles the desired DSLs - https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/MPSD34/Building+standalone+IDEs+for+your+languages

Comment: Hi @vaclav-pech, is there an update on this by any chance? I am looking to build a DSL for rights-driven development (think about what rights you need to respect, then code) and would like to build an app that stakeholders can use. The link to the confluence wiki, unfortunately, requires a login but there is no sign-up?